# How get binary data from PDF417

Tags: java, qr-code

I need to scan the code and get the bytes. Unfortunately, most services return a string immediately. How can I get bytes, you can in java

Comment: What services?  What have you tried?  What does “you can in Java” mean?  Can do what, exactly?

Comment: 1) Online decode. 2) Only online decoders and applications of android 3) How get my binary data in java , if possible